# How to access abstract current path in react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Using react-router v4, how should I go about getting the current abstract path. For example, I can access `this.props.location` when using `withRouter(...)` but this gives `/students/19`, when I want `students/:id` etc. This functionality is desired for a logging tool.

How should I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Use `this.props.match.id` as noted in [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params). Is this what you mean?

Comment: That is returning undefined for me. I want the literal string of the abstract URL, not the content of the query. Like if I visit the page `/item/5678` I want to get `/item/:id` literally so I can log that abstract path in a record

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.props.match.path`. I believe that's what you need.